# Devise User Show Page Controller not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, devise, routes, show

I'm using rails 3.1.3 (I believe the latest version) and in my app I am using the gem Devise for user auth. In order to add a user show (profile) page, I added a `Users_Controller.rb`

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def show
    @userProfile = User.find(params[:id])
    @user = current_user
    @title = @userProfile.name
  end
end
```

and in the `routes.rb` file i have `resources :users`.
I also have a simple `app/views/users/show.html.erb`. 
Now this all works fine and dandy when I manually go to localhost:3000/users/1 but, when I try to make a link to the profile `<%=link_to "My Profile", user_path(@user) %>` (This is in my `applicationcontroller.rb` incase that matters) I get an Action Controller: Exception `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}` 
BUT when i rake routes, action show and controller users show up. What am i doing wrong!!!
Please help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
<%=link_to "My Profile", user_path(@user) %>
```

do

```
<%=link_to "My Profile", @user %>
```

However, doing that in `ApplicationController` seems a bit strange. It should probably be in a view or layout file.

Comment: ahh I figured it out. instead of @user it should be current_user

Answer (score 1):

You should pass @user to the view where you render this link.

Comment: I render this link in the application controller. Should I pass it to the controller?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this alternate.

```
<%=link_to "My Profile", "/users/#{@user.id}" %>
```